# Getting missing column error whenever a model is saved

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm having trouble creating a model in django. I wrote a model like this:

```
from django.db import models
class FooModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

I run

```
manage.py syncdb
```

But when I'm in the shell, I can't save an instance. Every time I call it, it tells me it's missing a column

```
manage.py shell
>>from app.models import FooModel
>>foo = FooModel()
>>foo.name = 'foo'
>>foo.save()
DatabaseError: column "name" of relation "ecommerce_foomodel" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "ecommerce_foomodel" ("name") VALUES (E'123123as...
```

We're using postgres.

Comment: you might want to try to reset the app via, "manage.py reset ecommerce" or even recreate the db, then syncdb.

Comment: How do I recreate the database? Sorry, I'm kind of new to all this.

Comment: The reason you have to do the reset is that if you have an existing table called `ecommerce_foomodel` then `syncdb` will ignore it, it will not alter the table to add any new columns. It will only create the table if it does not exist.

Comment: I would just use pgadminIII to delete and recreate the db, if you're using postgres and reset doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database table was created before you added the corresponding fields.

So, you can recreate all of the tables of that app (in case you don't have any useful data) using:

```
python manage.py reset ecommerce
```

Or, you should migrate the database to the latest version using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).